# When does $\sigma$-finiteness come in?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I have a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X, \mu)$, a constant $p \in [1,\infty)$, a sequence $(f_n)$ in $L^p(X,\mu)$ such that $||f_n||_p \leq 1$, and $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. with $f$ measurable. I want to show that $||f||_p \leq 1$.

We have that $||f_n||_p \leq 1$ implies $\int_X |f_n|^p\ d\mu \leq 1$, and $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. implies $|f_n|^p \rightarrow |f|^p$ a.e.. Thus, by Fatou, we have $$ \int_X |f|^p\ d\mu = \int_X \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|f_n|^p\ d\mu \leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X |f_n|^p\ d\mu \leq 1, $$
which seemingly implies that $||f||_p \leq 1$. I never used $\sigma$-finiteness of $X$, so I feel that I have made a significant mistake somewhere. I would appreciate if someone could point out whatever mistake there is in my argument.

Comment: Did you check whether $\sigma$-finiteness is a hypothesis in any of the various theorems that you applied, i.e. the theorems stating the implications/equations/inequalities that occur in your proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is fine and $\sigma$-finiteness is not needed.  Indeed, you can see immediately that $\sigma$-finiteness cannot be needed as a hypothesis, since $\|f_n\|_p<\infty$ already implies that the support of $f_n$ is $\sigma$-finite, so that all the functions involved vanish outside of a $\sigma$-finite subspace of $X$ and so the statement for general $X$ would follow immediately from the statement for $\sigma$-finite $X$.

Comment: Thank you! It's just that this problem came from a qualifying exam, but my solution was practically a one-liner, which made me hesitate a bit.